# CMake zlib Dependency Error on Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, zlib, openexr

I'm trying to build OpenEXR 2.2 on Windows, but the instructions that came with the download aren't working as expected. The instructions for IlmBase worked, but once I get to the OpenEXR instructions, it fails because of zlib. The steps at this point are:

```
3. Go to http://www.zlib.net and download zlib
```

So I went to this website and in the section that starts with: **The current release is publicly available here:** I downloaded  **zlib source code, version 1.2.8, zipfile format...**

Then, I moved on to the next step, which is where I get the error:

```
4. Launch a command window, navigate to the OpenEXR folder with 
CMakeLists.txt, and type command:     
    setlocal
    del /f CMakeCache.txt
    cmake 
      -DZLIB_ROOT=<zlib location>
      -DILMBASE_PACKAGE_PREFIX=<where you installed the ilmbase builds>
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<where you want to instal the openexr builds>
      -G "Visual Studio 10 Win64" ^
      ..\openexr
```

So here's the command I type:

```
cmake -DZLIB_ROOT=C:\Users\erik\Documents\zlib-1.2.8 -DILMBASE_PACKAGE_PREFIX=C:\Users\erik\Documents\ilmbase-2.2.0\bin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\erik\Documents\ilmbase-2.2.0\bin -G "Visual Studio 10 Win64" ^..\openexr-2.2.0
```

And here's the error I get:

> Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY) (found version "1.2.8")

First problem is, the instructions don't say anything about ZLIB_LIBRARY. Second is, the zlib download looks like it's all source code. No .lib or .dll files are involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have downloaded only the source code. You need to compile it first. Or download the pre-compiled DLL: "zlib compiled DLL" from the zlib homepage.

`ZLIB_LIBRARY` will be derived from `ZLIB_DIR`, so this part is correct.

Comment: So step 3.5: Build zlib then set ZLIB_ROOT to the build directory.